# how to use mysql while loop with xlsxwriter class?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using xlsxwriter but nothing work for me, I tried a dozen of things to transfer mysql database row data to excel row data but nothing worked :(

```
<?php
include_once("xlsxwriter.class.php");
include("connection.php");
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$filename = "PM.xlsx";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($filename).'"');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');


$rows = array(); 

                   $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(jobcard.Open_date_time,' %d-%b-%y') AS datee,vehicles_data.Frame_no, jobcard.Jobc_id,jobcard.serv_nature,jobcard.Customer_name,jobc_invoice.Lnet, jobc_invoice.Pnet, jobc_invoice.Snet, jobcard.Mileage,customer_data.cust_type,vehicles_data.model_year,jobcard.Veh_reg_no,jobcard.comp_appointed, customer_data.mobile,IF(variant_codes.Make IS NULL,'Others',variant_codes.Make) as make FROM `jobcard` LEFT OUTER JOIN jobc_invoice ON jobcard.Jobc_id=jobc_invoice.Jobc_id LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles_data ON jobcard.Vehicle_id=vehicles_data.Vehicle_id LEFT OUTER JOIN variant_codes ON vehicles_data.Model=variant_codes.Model LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_data ON jobcard.Customer_id=customer_data.Customer_id ORDER BY `make` ASC";

                   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
 while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                   {
                        $rows[] = $rowz;
                   }



$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->setAuthor('Some Author'); 
foreach($rows as $row)
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row);
$writer->writeToStdOut();

exit(0);
```

Even tried this, playing with arrays but nothing fruitful yet.

```
$row_excel=array();
$row_numb=0;
 $writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->setAuthor('Some Author');             
                   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                   {
                       $row_excel[$row_numb]=$row;
                       $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row_excel[$row_numb]);
```

$row_numb++;
                       }

```
$writer->writeToStdOut();
exit(0);
```

Comment: What happens instead if it "doesn't work"? Is there any error message involved? Have you checked whether the database query itself returns the proper rows?

Comment: Yes i check the query it works fine but code creating problem, it is excel could not open the file because file extension is not valid or file is corrupt.

Comment: What does the file contain instead? Have you tried opening it using Notepad?

Comment: no sir, i will check now

Comment: it showing some unreadable text, 65KB file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    $data = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
        $data[$i] = $row[$i];
    }

    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $data);
}

$writer->writeToStdOut();
exit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i tried but still excel file not opening and notepad is empty.

Comment: I think the problem is with your data. Can you show us the result if you print_r the $row?

Comment: Yes u r right, I forget connecting the query with $result variable.   now notepad show unreadable text of 65kb but excel still says its currupt file and not showing data in it :(

Comment: even tried this... $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $data[$i]); but still shows file is currupt.

Comment: Maybe your data has special characters that might cause error on xlsxwriter's writeCell function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {


echo "<br/>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
        $data[$i] = $row[$i];
        echo $row[$i];
    }

}
```

I tried this code and it shows me data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm giving answer to bit old question but it may help someone if having same issue like @Rocky Rock and me.

Additionally I've to handle a large number of rows say 50,000 to 1,00,000. So I even tried some other solutions like chunking my result and tried to export into csv etc etc.

I also tried everything with force download with header and $writer->writeToStdOut(); but every logic goes into the vain.

But finally after day or two work around I coded as give and get rid of everything, believe me it can also download 1,00,000 rows in merely 20 seconds..
This is my code so instead of session variables of query and filename you can use whatever you like. Also I'd put some dummy variable as it is for one of our client.

```
<?php
    include your required libraries..

    include_once("lib/xlsxwriter.class.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Download IDs</title>

</head>
<body>

        <?php
            $sqlsel = $_SESSION['rptQry'];
            $ressql = mysqli_query($sqlsel);
            $currentdt = date('Ymdhis');
            $filename = $currentdt."_".$_SESSION['rptFileName'];
            $header = array(
                'Header1'=>'integer',               
                'Header 2'=>'integer',              
                'Header 3'=>'string',
                'Header 4' =>'string'
            );      

            $dataArray = array();

            $writer = new XLSXWriter();
            $writer->setAuthor('Adaptable Services');
            $writer->writeSheetHeader('ExportedIDs', $header);

            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($ressql)){
                $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1',$res);
            }

            $writer->writeToFile('/var/www/html/tmpxls/'.$filename);
            echo '<script>location.href="www.example.com/tmpxls/'.$filename.'";</script>';
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```